# How to access request object inside Item Pipeline Scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I have a item pipeline to process prices. I am having errors while processing item in this pipeline. But scrapy error doesn't tells which url produced error. Is there any way i can access the request object inside the pipeline

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    """
        :param self:
        :param item:
        :param spider:
    """
    print dir(spider) # No request object here...
    quit()
    if not all(item['price']):
        raise DropItem

    item['price']['new'] = float(re.sub(
        "\D", "", item['price']['new']))
    item['price']['old'] = float(re.sub(
        "\D", "", item['price']['old']))
    try:
        item['price']['discount'] = math.ceil(
            100 - (100 * (item['price']['new'] /
                          item['price']['old'])))
    except ZeroDivisionError as e:
        print "Error in calculating discount {item} {request}".format(item=item, request=spider.request) # here I want to see the culprit url...
        raise DropItem

    return item
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't from an ItemPipeline, you would be able to access the response (and response.url) from an spider middleware but I think the easier solution would be to add a temporary `url` field assigned when you yield the item, something like:

```
yield {...
       'url': response.url,
       ...}
```

The the url can be easily accessed inside the pipeline.

Comment: Is this possible that instead of adding new field to my Item object. I can somehow attach request url to the spider object manually in my spider class?

Comment: If your object has some sort of unique `id` I think you could do it keeping a dictionary `id => response.url` in your spider, but if you don't have that I would not advise it, btw, why are you using the regexes there and not in the spider itself?, also you could change the discount calculation replacing `item['price']['old']` by `item['price']['new']` whenever you receive zero there.

Comment: I am using regex in Pipeline because that is the centralized place to process prices. I am avoiding to put data manipulation logic in spider(s) because its not spiders job IMHO

Comment: for your other part about replacing. In the pipleline i already made sure that both variables will be available. Exactly thats what i did `old_price = copy.copy(new_price)`.

Answer (score 2):

In your spider class, whatever class variables you define here, can be accessed within your pipeline via `spider.variable_name`

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "walmart"
    my_var = "TEST"
    my_dict = {'test': "test_val"}
```

Now in your pipeline you can do `spider.name`, `spider.my_var`, `spider.my_dict`.

Comment: Yeah, that would be the better way

Comment: I will wait for few items if i could find request attached to spider anyhow. Otherwise i will mark your answer as accepted. Thanks

Comment: Not item, Spider actually. I doubt since the item is yeild from spider class and spider itself always have access to request object. Why on Pipeline it loses that information.

Comment: And actually this approach won't work because the spider yield several requests each with different url its not a one time declaration.